# How do you change an ng-style element with an ng-click element in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a simple 4x4 table and a 4x1 table. The 4x4 table a table of white squares. The 4x1 table is a list of 4 colors. Ideally, I'd like to click on an element in the 4x1 table (a color) and click on an element in the 4x4 table and change the background color of that particular element, not the entire 4x4 table. So, if I click on the color blue, and then block (2,2), then block (2,2) will change to blue. Right now, this is what I have:

[image]
[image]

```
<table>
<td ng-style="{'background-color':'blue'}"></td>
<td ng-style="{'background-color':'green'}"></td>
<td ng-style="{'background-color':'orange'}"></td>
<td ng-style="{'background-color':'red'}"></td>
</table>
```

So here, I know I must add some identifier for the colors to capture them, but I am not certain how at the moment.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td ng-style="getColor()" ng-click="changeColor()"></td>
    <td ng-style="getColor()" ng-click="changeColor()"></td>
    <td ng-style="getColor()" ng-click="changeColor()"></td>
    <td ng-style="getColor()" ng-click="changeColor()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td ng-style="getColor()" ng-click="changeColor()"></td>
    <td ng-style="getColor()" ng-click="changeColor()"></td>
    <td ng-style="getColor()" ng-click="changeColor()"></td>
    <td ng-style="getColor()" ng-click="changeColor()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td ng-style="getColor()" ng-click="changeColor()"></td>
    <td ng-style="getColor()" ng-click="changeColor()"></td>
    <td ng-style="getColor()" ng-click="changeColor()"></td>
    <td ng-style="getColor()" ng-click="changeColor()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td ng-style="getColor()" ng-click="changeColor()"></td>
    <td ng-style="getColor()" ng-click="changeColor()"></td>
    <td ng-style="getColor()" ng-click="changeColor()"></td>
    <td ng-style="getColor()" ng-click="changeColor()"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And here, I have a table where I am hoping to use getColor to set the color value, initially blank or white, and changeColor to change that.

At this very moment, getColor looks like:

```
$scope.getColor = function(){
    return{
        "background-color":"white"
    }
}
```

And changeColor looks like:

```
$scope.changeColor = function(){
    return{
        "background-color":"'"+$scope.newColor+"'"
    }
}
```

Of course, this does not work for a variety of reasons, but I would like to know how to get the simple functionality that I am hoping for.

Comment: not really clear how this needs to work but if click is supposed to change things then you need to pass argument(s) to that function and probably same for `getColor()`

Comment: I am trying to build something like Paint Shop, if you are familiar with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd approach it like this...

1. On clicking a colour cell, set a temporary `nextColour` scope property
2. On clicking a grid cell, set its background colour to the `nextColour` value. You can keep track of each cell's colour by using a two-dimensional array.

```css
pre { display: block; }
td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<main ng-app>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="colour in ['blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red'] track by $index"
          ng-style="{'background-color': colour}"
          ng-click="$parent.nextColour = colour">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <pre>nextColour = {{nextColour|json}}</pre>
  
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in [0,1,2,3] track by $index">
      <td ng-repeat="col in [0,1,2,3] track by $index"
          ng-style="{'background-color': colour[row][col]}"
          ng-click="colour[row][col] = nextColour">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</main>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
```

Note that you have to use `$parent` when setting a value within `ng-repeat` in order to not just set it within the `ng-repeat` directive scope.

Answer (score 1):

You could have an array of objects that represent each cell and store the color there. e.g.

JS

```
$scope.cells = [
    [{}, {}, {}, {}],
    [{}, {}, {}, {}],
    [{}, {}, {}, {}],
    [{}, {}, {}, {}]
];

$scope.colors = ['purple', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'];
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <td ng-repeat="color in colors" ng-style="{'background-color':color}" ng-click="activeColor = color"></td>
</table>

<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in cells">
        <td ng-repeat="cell in row" ng-style="{'background-color':cell.color}" ng-click="cell.color = activeColor"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You're going to run into a scoping issue setting `activeColour` within the `ng-repeat`

Comment: Also, you have a typo in `"cell in rows"`. Should be `row`

Comment: fixed typo. And yeah it would be better to use controller as syntax to avoid the scope issue.

Comment: The problem is that you're only setting `activeColor` inside the `ng-repeat` directive scope so it won't actually be available to the second table. You could use a controller function to set the value or use *"controller as"* as you pointed out